# User input registration then geocoded into database

Tags: javascript, sql-server, google-maps, coldfusion

I've been having quite a bit of trouble with Google Maps API and a database driven map. In a previous question I had inquired about faster geocoding of addresses to a map and basically what I need to do is store Lat/Lng into the database and create a map from there, instead of geocoding while the map is loading.

However, I'm unsure exactly how to do this. I know the basic premise - 1) User registers and enters in their address. 2) Database should store the user's information, along with the address. 3) Address needs to be geocoded and then added to the Lat/Lng fields in the database. 4)Markers can then be placed on the map by looping through a query involving the Lat/Lng fields.

Any ideas how to do this? I'm using ColdFusion, SQL Server.

Comment: The basic premise sounds okay. Where exactly are you unsure?

Comment: How to get the coordinates from google's geocode and store them into the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Google's Geocoding Service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/index.html) for this. The API is dead simple. You send an address in the url and it returns some xml with the geocoded result. Even better, there's a project on RiaForge called [Google Geocoder v3](http://googlegeocoder3.riaforge.org/) that will do all the work for you.

**Here's some sample code of the CFC:**

```
<cfinvoke component="googlegeocoder3" method="googlegeocoder3" returnvariable="variables.geocode_query1">     
  <cfinvokeargument name="address" value="1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA">
  <cfinvokeargument name="ShowDetails" value="false">
</cfinvoke>

<cfdump var="#variables.geocode_query1#">
```

As for when to do the geocoding, you have two options. One is just to do it when they register - take the address from the registration form, call the geocoding service to get the lat/lng and then save everything to the database. The other option is to save the address from registration and then have a separate scheduled task to periodically checks and geocodes any un-geocoded addresses.

Comment: Thank you very much Peter. Your two options of geocoding were exactly what I had in mind. I like the first one better as the user joining may want to see their marker on the map immediately. I will work on this in the afternoon and let you know what I come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Well after working with Peter's advice, and the Google Geocoder v3, I threw together my own stuff because the Google Geocoder v3 cfc wouldn't work.

```
        <!---Geocode the address and convert it to Lat/Lng --->
        <cfset address2geocode = '#Form.Client_Address#, #Form.Client_City#, #Form.Client_State#'>

        <cfhttp url="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=#address2geocode#&sensor=true" />
        <cfset geocodedXML = #xmlParse(cfhttp.filecontent)#>

      <!--- Add the record to the database--->
      <cfquery datasource="#dsn#" name="AddMember">
        INSERT INTO BSC_Clients (Client_Lng, Client_Lat)
        VALUES ('#geocodedXML.GeocodeResponse.result.geometry.location.lng.XmlText#', '#geocodedXML.GeocodeResponse.result.geometry.location.lat.XmlText#' )
      </cfquery>
```

This will effectively take the Address + City + State given (throw all other user information in database, which isn't shown in the code) and convert that to Lat/Long values which will be stored back into the database. The google map should then show the new address via a marker